# How to replace/update authorization key for an ArcGIS Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-license-manager

I need to switch the authorization key of an ArcGIS Enterprise Geodatabase (in Postgresql). I am on 10.3 and based on the scarce documentation I have found, ESRI is moving tools that allow such administration to arcpy and the GUI, however, the particular tool that is on the docs in pre 10.3 era, [`sdesetup`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/serveradmin/sdesetup.htm) is not available with ArcGIS installation (Server or Desktop). So basically I am wondering how to switch keys.

I have tried the "Enable Enterprise Geodatabase" tool with no avail saying that it is already authorized.

Comment: Only Esri or its local distributors will be able to help you with this.

Comment: Based on the comments in this [blog](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2015/02/18/generate-a-keycodes-file-toauthorize-an-enterprise-geodatabase-without-having-to-install-arcgis-server/) it doesnt sound like its possible to switch the authorization on it after the fact. Only to update once expired. But I'm not an expert in this area.

Comment: You may be able to use a 10.2 `sdesetup` utility to update a 10.3 server, or you can alter the row in the `sde_server_config` row (be careful with that!). 10.4 added the [Update Enterprise Geodatabase License](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/update-enterprise-geodatabase-license.htm) tool

Answer (score 3):

In 10.3.1 the Enable Enterprise Geodatabase tool does not update the "AUTH_KEY" in SDE_server_config table of your database. See the image below. The suggested workaround from our ESRI rep said that there is a tool in 10.4 that handles this properly but since we are running 10.3.1 you have to update this value manually.

To do this, create a new geodatabase with the keycodes files located under the "C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\License10.3\sysgen" folder on your ArcGIS server. Then open the SDE_server_config table on your new database, either through SSMS or whatever tool you use to view SQL data and find the "AUTH_KEY" record and copy its value somewhere.

Then create a new query and update that record in each database that requires the new keycode license to be applied.

The SQL Server query that we used was as follows (substitute your database name and license info in the query, and adjust the syntax based on what SQL system you are using):

```
USE [YOUR_EXISTING_DATABASE_NAME_HERE] GO UPDATE SDE_server_config SET char_prop_value = 'VALUE_COPIED_FROM_NEW_GEODATABASES_SERVER_CONFIG_TABLE' WHERE prop_name = 'AUTH_KEY'
```

If you have multiple databases, then all you will need to do is switch the database names and the rest of the syntax remains the same.

[image: AUTH_KEY Setting in SDE_server_config table]